# Search Between can hide the past product_Name transaction

Tags: java

//this is my for loop

```
DefaultTableModel model =(DefaultTableModel)inventory_Table.getModel();
Object[] row = new Object[12];

for(int i = 0; i < Listass.size(); i++) {
    row[1] = Listass.get(i).getType();
    row[2] = Listass.get(i).getProduct();
    row[3] = Listass.get(i).getPacking();
    row[4] = Listass.get(i).getQuantity();
    row[5] = Listass.get(i).getAmount();
    row[6] = Listass.get(i).getSupplier();
    row[7] = Listass.get(i).getPONumber();
    row[8] = Listass.get(i).getUnitPrice();
    row[9] = Listass.get(i).getTDR();
    row[10] = Listass.get(i).getSDR();
    row[0] = Listass.get(i).getDate();
    row[11] = Listass.get(i).getProductNumber();
    model.addRow(row);
}
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the lines:

```
Object[] row = new Object[12];
for(int i = 0; i < Listass.size(); i++) {
    ...
    model.addRow(row);
}
```

You only assign 1 value to `row` (the new array). So you are actually adding the same array reference multiple times to the model. `addRow` doesn't copy the data in the array - it just stores a reference to it to represent the data in the row. Subsequent iterations override that data so all rows end up showing the final values.

The solution is to create a new array inside the loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Listass.size(); i++) {
    Object[] row = new Object[12];
    ...
    model.addRow(row);
}
```

Now each row points to a different array.

Be aware that there are several stylist issues with the code you posted. I haven't corrected any of those here but you should read a Java style guide and try to conform to expected standards in the industry.